# items not being displayed on table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been trying to create this search app where I can display the items in a table and delete items using react redux. However, on the initial load, the app shows a table but there is no data in the table. It's an empty table. If i search for another movie name which have more than one movie for that search term, then 2 tables would be shown but I want to show everything on the same table itself. The delete button is not working as well. Is there something wrong with my action and reducer files?

Action.js

```
import {
  FETCH_MOVIE_PENDING,
  FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_MOVIE_ERROR,
  DELETE_MOVIE
} from "./types";

const fetchMoviePendig = () => ({
  type: FETCH_MOVIE_PENDING
});

const fetchMovieSuccess = json => ({
  type: FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS,
  payload: json
});

const fetchMovieError = error => ({
  type: FETCH_MOVIE_ERROR,
  payload: error
});

export const fetchMovie = name => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchMoviePendig());
    try {
      const url = `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/movies/search/?Title=${name}`;
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const result = await response.json(response);

      console.log(result);
      dispatch(fetchMovieSuccess(result.data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(fetchMovieError(error));
    }
  };
};

export const deleteEvent = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_MOVIE,
      payload: id
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Reducer

```
import {
  FETCH_MOVIE_PENDING,
  FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_MOVIE_ERROR,
  DELETE_MOVIE
} from "../action/types";

const initialState = {
  data: [],
  loading: false,
  error: ""
};

const moviesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_MOVIE_PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: [...state.data, action.payload]
      };
    case FETCH_MOVIE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    case DELETE_MOVIE:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.filter(movie => movie.id !== action.payload)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default moviesReducer;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMovie } from "./action/movieActions";

import Input from "./components/Input";
import MovieTable from "./components/MovieTable";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    searchInput: "The Rain"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getMovieList(this.state.searchInput);
  }

  _getMovie = () => {
    this.props.getMovieList(this.state.searchInput);
  };

  _onChangeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({
      searchInput: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(this.state.searchInput);
  };
  render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.props.movies;
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <div>
          <h2 className="center white-text">Movie Search</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="container">
          <Input
            value={this.state.searchInput}
            onChange={this._onChangeHandler}
            onClick={this._getMovie}
          />
          <div className="row">
            {loading ? (
              <p>Loading</p>
            ) : (
              data.map(item => (
                <MovieTable
                  key={item.imdbID}
                  year={item.Year}
                  name={item.Title}
                  movieId={item.imdbId}
                />
              ))
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    movies: state.movies
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getMovieList: name => dispatch(fetchMovie(name))
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello please take a look at the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-wind-4hgq2?file=/src/App.js

I have edited

```
 <MovieTable
        data={data.map(d => ({
          year: d.Year,
          name: d.Title,
          movieId: d.imdbId
        }))}
      />
```

and

```
case FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    data: action.payload
  };
```

And ... Currently the delete button has no event, that's why it can't work

Comment: thanks it worked. can you also please look at the deleteMovie function? it says that deleteMovie is not a function.. https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hertz-c7dr8?file=/src/components/MovieTable.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-hooks-fxe86?file=/src/App.js take a look at the update

Answer (score 0):

I see data having the following pattern:

```
 Object {page: 1, per_page: 10, total: 1, total_pages: 1, data: Array[1]}
page: 1
per_page: 10
total: 1
total_pages: 1
data: Array[1]
0: Object
Title: "Sin in the Rain"
Year: 2006
imdbID: "tt1072449"
```

And you are accessing wrong properties in the component render logic, can you fix that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Duplicate table is created the way you have written the logic.
   Pass the data to MovieTable component and let it render and create the table
   and fill it.
2. In reducer (FETCH_MOVIE_SUCCESS) you need don't need to append data you have to
   replace or use the current movie data only.

Comment: can you please show me in the sandbox with the fix? I'm not sure how to fix it. I did the change to the reducer as you said. but not sure about the table

Comment: at least it shows the name of the movie now. but how do I fix the duplicate table and delete button?